# make headers_install in ubuntu is throwing an error

Tags: c, unix, ubuntu, kernel, ubuntu-11.10

In order to use some kernel headers like cpu.h in C coding, I want to install kernel headers to /usr/include/ directory. I am using "make headers_install" command for that. But system is throwing the following error. Does anyhow have idea of how to resolve it?

```
make headers_install

CHK     include/linux/version.h
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-17-generic/ubuntu/include/linux/aufs_type.h', needed by `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-17-generic/usr/include/linux/.install'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [linux] Error 2
make: *** [headers_install] Error 2
```

My kernel version is: 3.0.0-17-generic
Do I need to install anything more for operation "make headers_install" to be successful?

Comment: Oh! Thank for editing Al-Qudsi, I forget to format the question before posting it.

Answer (score 1):

You may find it simpler just to aptitude install linux-headers-3.0.0-17-generic.

Comment: Thanks, But "aptitute install linux-headers-3.0.0-17-generic" is actually performing a normal install or upgrade of packages. But I want the kernel packages to be in /usr/include, in order to build user space programs using kernel headers which are in /usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-17-generic/arch .

Comment: Right, it's a normal package, and inside the package are precisely the kernel headers you're looking for. They will be installed to /usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-17/ .